# How to filter objects with another object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, filter

Working on a font library, I store fonts like this:

```
var fonts = [
    {
        name: "Foo",
        style: "Bar",
        families: [
            { name: "A", parent: "B" },
            { name: "C", parent: "D" }
        ]
    } // and so on...
];
```

And I want to filter out fonts whose families list contains `{ name: "A", parent: "B" }`.

The filter looks like `var selection = [{ name: "A", parent: "B" }]`

Actually, the code look like this:

```
// Triggers when a new family is added to the filter
$scope.$on('filter:changed', function(e, selection) {

    _.each($scope.fonts, function(font) {

        _.each(font.families, function(family) {

            _.each(selection, function(item) {

                if(_.isMatch(family, item)) {
                    console.log('font', font);
                    console.log('has a match for family', family);
                } else {
                    console.log('no match for family', family);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**What is the best way to do it without performance impact**, as there will be thousands font objects in the future?

Comment: Since you're using underscore. You could look @ `findWhere` or `where`

Comment: @dcodesmith is right, use `where` to get the array or `findWhere` if you want only one result

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The selection might not be a single object as in the example, but an array of objects. I think I should iterate over `$scope.fonts`, then over the selectors (`selection` array) and test them with `_.where`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using underscore use `filter`

From [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org):

> _.filter(list, predicate, [context]) Alias: select  Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a
>   truth test (predicate).

So your filter would be (use this only if you want to manipulate data for each object, otherwise use `where`):

```
var myFamilyMatch = { name: "A", parent: "B" };

var selection = _.filter(fonts, function(font){
  return _find(font.families, function(family){
     return family == myFamilyMatch;
  };
});
```

Or simply (and better) use `where` as @dcodesmith suggested:

> _.where(list, properties)  Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value
>   pairs listed in properties.

Underscore will take care of performance for you, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

[underscore#where](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

```
$scope.$on('filter:changed', function(e, selection) {
    var multiselection,
        singleSelection;
    _.each($scope.fonts, function(font) {
        multiselection = _.where(font.families, { name: "A", parent: "B" }); //all matching objects
        singleSelection = _.findWhere(font.families, { name: "A", parent: "B" }); // single matching object
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/d2smujg0/)**